# Pytorch not detecting multiple GPUs

Tags: pytorch, multi-gpu

I have 10 GPUs available and 1 GPU (e.g. GPU#9) is in use by another torch process. I would like to run another process on any of the remaining GPUs (e.g. GPU#2, GPU#3, GPU#4) but I always get the error message:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable

I tried several options and none of them worked:

OPTION 1: Selecting GPUs on python script

```
import os
os.environ[“CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER”] = ‘PCI_BUS_ID’
os.environ[“CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES”] = ‘2,3,4’
print(f’[INFO] Using GPU: {torch.cuda.current_device()}‘)
print(f’[INFO] Available GPUs: {torch.cuda.device_count()}')
for d in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
   print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(d))
```

It recognises the 3 GPUs and the process will now assign them as GPU#0, GPU#1 and GPU#3 within that process.

```
[INFO] Using GPU: 2,3,4
[INFO] Available GPUs: 10
GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
```

OPTION 2: Selecting GPU on command line:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3,4 python gdxray_cganTrainer.py
```

and I check on linux using

```
env | grep CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3,4
```

None of the above 2 options work as still get the CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable. It looks like it knows that the already running process on GPU#9 was assigned as GPU#0 and when I select GPU#2,3,4 the first GPU will be assigned as GPU#0 in the new process. But it shouldn't be as they are different processes

I am using torch 1.8.0, python 3.8.8, cudatoolkit 11.1.1

Any help?

Comment: What is your CUDA version? Which version of PyTorch/cudatoolkit is installed on your machine?

Comment: I am using cuda v11.0, pytorch 1.8.0. Using tensorflow I do not have any problem to select a particular GPU. It only happens with pytorch

Comment: Which version of cudatoolkit is installed on your machine?

Comment: cudatoolkit 11.1.1

Comment: If you set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3`, does your process actually go to GPU 3 or it stays at GPU 0?

Comment: By default if you set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3, that will be GPU 0 within pytorch, but I get the same error message.